# How to find phrase in file prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, dcg

I am trying to find phrase in a file using Prolog and if its finded just returing true. The problem is that i dont have idea how to use this phrase_from_file/2. I made something like that.

```
search(Smthing):-   
    phrase_from_file(Smthing,'b.txt');
    false.
```

executing: 
    search('myphrase').

b.txt file:

```
(fs1111myphrase111asd)
 aaaamyphrase
```

Can anyone show me how to implement it?

Comment: As an aside, you don't need `query -> true ; false`. The query will already succeed or fail, so the `->` here is nearly redundant producing the same result, except it will prevent backtracking to query for more than one solution. Backtracking probably doesn't apply for `phrase_from_file/2` so it is serving no purpose.

Comment: ok already changed it.

Comment: You don't need the `; false` either, for the same reason. At that point, the `phrase_from_file` call has already failed. Why do you need to call `false`?

Comment: Of interest: [Prolog DCG Primer](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/dcg)

Answer (score 2):

*The* major attraction of `library(pio)` is that it simply applies a DCG to a file.

So, first, you need to have a basic understanding of **DCGs** in Prolog.
 See [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) for more information.

Next, focus on how you would *normally* describe the task with a DCG. You want to describe a *list* that contains `[m,y,p,h,r,a,s,e`], or—speaking in codes—`[109,121,etc.]`, as a sublist.

A useful nonterminal for describing *anything at all* is:

```
... --> [] | [_], ... .
```

And so we can describe a list with the given property as:

```
contains_myphrase -->
        ...,
        "myphrase",
        ... .
```

The beauty of this is that we can already *test* it interactively:

```
?- length(Ls, _), phrase(contains_myphrase, Ls).
Ls = [109, 121, 112, 104, 114, 97, 115, 101] ;
Ls = [109, 121, 112, 104, 114, 97, 115, 101, _8260] ;
Ls = [_8212, 109, 121, 112, 104, 114, 97, 115, 101] ;
Ls = [109, 121, 112, 104, 114, 97, 115, 101, _8260|...] ;
Ls = [_8212, 109, 121, 112, 104, 114, 97, 115, 101|...] ;
Ls = [_8212, _8218, 109, 121, 112, 104, 114, 97, 115|...] .
```

**And then** we can also apply the same DCG to a file:

```
?- phrase_from_file(contains_myphrase, 'b.txt').
true .
```

It is straight-forward to *generalize* this so that you can specify what you are looking for as an *argument*.

However, I recommend to first do this *without* using `phrase_from_file/2`. Simply work on the DCG, and study the different encodings. In particular, you should find out the difference between:

- **atoms**
- lists of **codes**
- lists of **characters**.

Make the following work *first*:

```
?- phrase(contains(MyPhrase), Ls).
```

This should hold *iff* `Ls` contains `MyPhrase` as a sublist, where `MyPhrase` *could* for example be specified as a list of codes. I say "could" because *you* should pick an encoding that is most convenient and natural for your use case. From personal experience, I can tell you that using lists of *characters* is by far more convenient than using lists of *codes*. A Prolog flag you may find relevant in this context is called `double_quotes`.

Once you have this solved with a DCG, it is straight-forward to use `phrase_from_file/2` on it.

Answer (score 1):

To use the various `phrase` predicates, you will have to understand Prolog's DCG (definite clause grammar) system for defining grammars. Here is one tutorial: http://www.pathwayslms.com/swipltuts/dcg/, and there should be DCG chapters in every other reasonable Prolog text. Note also that `phrase_from_file/2` is an SWI-Prolog extension that to my knowledge is not present on other Prolog systems.

So you need to write a grammar that matches an arbitary sequence of input items, they your pattern, then an arbitrary rest. All this is complicated by the fact that SWI-Prolog knows several kinds of string-like things: strings, atoms, lists of codes, and lists of chars.

Anyway, here is an example I adapted very slightly from the SWI-Prolog docs at http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=pio:

```
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).

file_contains(File, Pattern) :-
        phrase_from_file(match(Pattern), File).

match(Pattern) -->
        string(_),
        string(Pattern),
        string(_).
```

You can run this as follows:

```
?- file_contains('b.txt', `myphrase`).
true ;
true ;
false.
```

This is not *very* informative, but the two `true` results mean that your pattern occurred twice in the input file. The final `false` means that there were no further occurences after these two.

Note that your phrase must be enclosed in backtick characters (`) to make SWI-Prolog interpret it as a list of character codes (the underlying representation of file contents by phrase_from_file/2).